# mod_proxy 502 Proxy Error when upload a file

Tags: apache, file-upload, proxy, lighttpd, mod-proxy

I'm trying to configure the following environment: a VPS running apache and mod_proxy to proxy another server running at home (the backend). I'm able to download files but when I try to upload files the POST request fails with this error:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /upload/upload.php.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

What I don't understand is why it works for files as low as 500 bytes. And it does quickly! However, when I try to upload a tiny 4kb file, it takes forever until the error is reached. As expected, the upload works flawlessly when the backend is accessed directly, without the VPS. I tried many configurations for both sides, also tried to increase the timeout but I don't think this is the way to go. The backend has mod_access installed and it doesn't log anything when the file upload fails.

The apache logs the following:

```
[Thu Nov 07 22:26:03.044309 2013] [proxy_http:error] [pid 9173] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 177.148.252.99:54097] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server myhome.com, referer: http://frontend.com/upload/
[Thu Nov 07 22:26:03.044423 2013] [proxy:error] [pid 9173] [client 177.148.252.99:54097] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /upload/upload.php, referer: http://frontend.com/upload/
```

The VPS is running Apache 2.4.6 and the server running at home is a Lighttpd 1.4.32 with SSL.

The virtual host redirecting to the backend is configured as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@frontend.com
        ServerName frontend.com
        ProxyPass        / http://backend.com/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://backend.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Front-end:
http://frontend.com/upload/

Back-end:
http://backend.com/upload/

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The error you're seeing is due to a timeout of the proxy connection to the back-end system.  You need to set the ProxyTimeout value to something larger than the default.  I would recommend that you start with a value of 60 seconds and see how that works.

```
ProxyTimeout 60
```

In addition, I agree with Varghese that you want to set the environment variable in order to configure the connection to send the data in chunks.  Unfortunately, there is some confusion over whether the correct setting should be, so you can try either of these:

```
SetEnv proxy-sendchunked  1
```

or

```
SetEnv proxy-sendchunks  1
```

Good luck. It's a frustrating problem.

---

Environment variables availables in `mod_proxy`:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http.html

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the similar kind of issue and got resolved with the  statement, I put after the `ProxyPassReverse` statement.

The command you have to use is : `SetEnv proxy-sendchunks 1`